# Local pointer to shared memory in CUDA

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

How can I make each thread in the thread block has his own pointer to shared memory? I found some example of declaration of such pointers:

```
int __shared__ *p;
__shared__ int array[256];

p = &array[threadId];
```

Is this right or is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No that is not the correct way. In that example code, `p` is shared so it means that every thread in the block would be trying to access the same piece of memory. You could do it like this if `threadId` was the unique thread index with the block:

```
int *p;
__shared__ int array[256];

p = &array[threadId];
```

In this case the compiler would use either a register or thread local memory to store the unique address of an element in static shared memory allocation `array` for each thread in the block.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought I saw it in [http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=35294] but there is declaration like `int *__shared__ p;` It should be pointer stored in thread local memory and point to shared memory. Is it correct?

Comment: no that isn't correct. You can safely disregard everything in that thread - it is from 2008 when CUDA was new, the compiler was primitive and not many people understood the fine details of the language extensions and how they mapping to hardware.

Comment: How can I enforce p to be stored in a register?

Comment: @spurra, by declaring `p` as a local variable.

Answer (score -2):

You are right. A better way is Dynamic allocation of shared memory. An example is as fellow:

```
void __global__ test(){
extern __shared__ int s[];
int *p = &s[xx];

}

...
test<<<x,y, shared memory length>>>();
...
```

Comment: But the posted code in the question _isn't_ right. `*p` cannot be declared `__shared__`, that is a shared memory race.